# Infinite geometric series problem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

$$A_n=\frac{3}{4}-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3+....+\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$$
   $$B_n=1-A_n$$
   Find the minimum natural number $n_0$ such that $B_n>A_n\quad\forall\quad
   n>n_0$

My attempt is as follows:

$$A_n=\frac{\frac{3}{4}\left(1-\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^n\right)}{1-\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)}$$
$$A_n=\frac{3}{7}\left(1-\left(-1\right)^n\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\right)$$

As we have to find minimum natural number $n_0$ such that $B_n>A_n\quad\forall\quad
   n>n_0$

$$1-A_n>A_n$$
$$1>2A_n$$
$$\frac{1}{2}>\frac{3}{7}\left(1-\left(-1\right)^n\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\right)$$
$$\frac{7}{6}>\left(1-\left(-1\right)^n\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{6}>\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$$

It is easy to notice that if n is even, then this inequality always satisfies.

If n is odd, then we can write as:

$$2^{2n-1}>3^{n+1}$$

Lets check for odd values of n:

$n=1$

$$2>9$$

$n=3$

$${32>81}$$

$n=5$

$${512>729}$$

$n=7$

$${8192>6561}$$

So from $n>5$ , this equation will always be satisfied as 6 is even and for 7 we just checked.

So $n_0$ should be equal to $5$ but everywhere answer to this question is said to be 6.

Comment: For Equality $$log {1 \over 6}=n.log{3 \over 4}$$ or $$n=\frac{log 6}{log{4 \over 3}}=6.22$$

Comment: But see you have to calculate minimum $n_0$, so minimum $n_0$ should be 5, as for n=6 , inequality satisfies as n is even and also satisfies for n>=7 as proved.